# Design view not reflecting the values of a string array in List View

Tags: android, listview

I have a simple string array declared in the string resource file and want to populate it in a list view. Everything works fine when I test the app in my device. But in the android studio design view I get some default values I suppose which are the not the values in the string resource file.

I am wondering if this is a glitch, bug or am I doing something wrong here?

Strings.xml

```
<resources>
    <string name="app_name">Starbuzz</string>
    <string name="starbuzz_logo">Starbuzz logo</string>
    <string-array name="options">
        <item>Drinks</item>
        <item>Food</item>
        <item>Stores</item>
    </string-array>
</resources>
```

activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context="com.hfad.starbuzz.MainActivity">
<ImageView
    android:layout_width="200dp"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:src="@drawable/starbuzz_logo"
    android:contentDescription="@string/starbuzz_logo"/>
  <ListView
      android:id="@+id/list_options"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:entries="@array/options">
  </ListView>
</LinearLayout>
```

[image]

Comment: If it is an android design rule, that list view is not supposed to be rendered. Can anybody let me know why it is so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its Android Design rule, it displays in preview with just rendering the view in xml not with data. So if you wish to see data here, you need to run it in device or emulator.

Comment: Is this only for list data? I could see other text and images being rendered?

Comment: Yes it is for list only, other text and image will rendered easily. As for working with list you need to have adapter

Comment: That clears it up for me. To learn adapters in my next task :) . Thanks a lot @ankit patidar !

Answer (score 1):

I believe the screen you shared is a preview of your XML file in Android Studio which is perfectly fine. The preview of listview will always be shown as a default template. Your data entries for the listview will be populated only when you run the app either on the emulator or actual device.